# Firebase cloud function file upload

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-functions

I have a Javascript cloud function which resizes an image, stores each and writes the new signed url to the realtime database. It looks however that the new signed image url is publicly accessible.

Instead of the signed url, is it possible to obtain a downloadUrl for each new resized file, like the one obtained from a storage reference ?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking for.  Signed URL is functionally the same as a download URL - they provide public access to a file in Cloud Storage via HTTPS.

Comment: My question is can I obtain same format of url as download url which includes token as so fourth .

Comment: Why do you need it that way?  An URL is an URL.  They work the same way.